# empty output when scrapping loking for id name with beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried the following code to scrap the links in the links list but i get None output

```
links = ['https://www.glassdoor.com/partner/jobListing.htm?pos=101&ao=1136043&s=58&guid=0000018209b985b3814e13e6abec3f6b&src=GD_JOB_AD&t=SR&vt=w&ea=1&cs=1_968a1afd&cb=1658020530267&jobListingId=1007823714104&jrtk=3-0-1g84rj1gokf0t801-1g84rj1hdghre800-21320f35b2a9f6f4-', 'https://www.glassdoor.com/partner/jobListing.htm?pos=102&ao=1136043&s=58&guid=0000018209b985b3814e13e6abec3f6b&src=GD_JOB_AD&t=SR&vt=w&ea=1&cs=1_11e4da95&cb=1658020530267&jobListingId=1007830003866&jrtk=3-0-1g84rj1gokf0t801-1g84rj1hdghre800-6ad629ee4ebc1885-', 'https://www.glassdoor.com/partner/jobListing.htm?pos=103&ao=1136043&s=58&guid=0000018209b985b3814e13e6abec3f6b&src=GD_JOB_AD&t=SR&vt=w&cs=1_0ae3fe0c&cb=1658020530267&jobListingId=1008006371431&jrtk=3-0-1g84rj1gokf0t801-1g84rj1hdghre800-f24a3ad703626f08-']
 
for link in links:
    page = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.find(id="JobDescriptionContainer")
    print(div)
```

The page html is something like this:

```
<div id="Job view">
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>
            <div>
            <div>
                <header>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div id="JobDescriptionContainer">
                            <div>
                                <div>   
                                    <p... text>
                                    <p...text>
                                    <p...text>
                                    <h3 Responsabilities>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>....<li/>
                                        <li>....<li/>
                                        <li>....<li/>
                                    <h3 Qualifications>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>....<li/>
                                        <li>....<li/>
                                        <li>....<li/>
```

I want to get all the info from each link to create a data frame with all the link's information.
The text I want to get from each link is the text below the div whose name is 'JobDescriptionContainer'(the real links list contains 900 links)
Also i will like to separate in different data frame columns the text below 'responsibilities' and 'Qualifications' Can someone give me a hand with this?

Comment: In most cases where people try to scrape something from a web page but are surprised about there being no results from their script, the problem is that the data is loaded after the page loads, through some JavaScript. That may be the case here, but it's not possible to say for sure since the link you provided in the example is incomplete and doesn't actually load at all.

Comment: Actually, the links variable is a list with 3 links, so if you copy all of them together it won't work unless you iterate through the links list. I already double-checked the links one by one and they worked

Answer (score 1):

You must add `User-Agent` to the headers

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626 Safari/537.36'}

links = ['https://www.glassdoor.com/partner/jobListing.htm?pos=101&ao=1136043&s=58&guid=0000018209b985b3814e13e6abec3f6b&src=GD_JOB_AD&t=SR&vt=w&ea=1&cs=1_968a1afd&cb=1658020530267&jobListingId=1007823714104&jrtk=3-0-1g84rj1gokf0t801-1g84rj1hdghre800-21320f35b2a9f6f4-', 'https://www.glassdoor.com/partner/jobListing.htm?pos=102&ao=1136043&s=58&guid=0000018209b985b3814e13e6abec3f6b&src=GD_JOB_AD&t=SR&vt=w&ea=1&cs=1_11e4da95&cb=1658020530267&jobListingId=1007830003866&jrtk=3-0-1g84rj1gokf0t801-1g84rj1hdghre800-6ad629ee4ebc1885-', 'https://www.glassdoor.com/partner/jobListing.htm?pos=103&ao=1136043&s=58&guid=0000018209b985b3814e13e6abec3f6b&src=GD_JOB_AD&t=SR&vt=w&cs=1_0ae3fe0c&cb=1658020530267&jobListingId=1008006371431&jrtk=3-0-1g84rj1gokf0t801-1g84rj1hdghre800-f24a3ad703626f08-']

for link in links:
    page = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.find(id="JobDescriptionContainer")
    print(div)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a header to make the page think that your program is a browser

```
    import requests


    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


    user_agent_list = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
    ]
    user_agent = user_agent_list[0]
    #Set the headers 
    headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

    links = ['https://www.glassdoor.com/partner/jobListing.htm?pos=101&ao=1136043&s=58&guid=0000018209b985b3814e13e6abec3f6b&src=GD_JOB_AD&t=SR&vt=w&ea=1&cs=1_968a1afd&cb=1658020530267&jobListingId=1007823714104&jrtk=3-0-1g84rj1gokf0t801-1g84rj1hdghre800-21320f35b2a9f6f4-',
     'https://www.glassdoor.com/partner/jobListing.htm?pos=102&ao=1136043&s=58&guid=0000018209b985b3814e13e6abec3f6b&src=GD_JOB_AD&t=SR&vt=w&ea=1&cs=1_11e4da95&cb=1658020530267&jobListingId=1007830003866&jrtk=3-0-1g84rj1gokf0t801-1g84rj1hdghre800-6ad629ee4ebc1885-',
     'https://www.glassdoor.com/partner/jobListing.htm?pos=103&ao=1136043&s=58&guid=0000018209b985b3814e13e6abec3f6b&src=GD_JOB_AD&t=SR&vt=w&cs=1_0ae3fe0c&cb=1658020530267&jobListingId=1008006371431&jrtk=3-0-1g84rj1gokf0t801-1g84rj1hdghre800-f24a3ad703626f08-']

    for link in links:
        page = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        div = soup.find(id="JobDescriptionContainer")
        print(div)
```